# Checking for CO2 leaks

Tags: techniques, equipment, carbonation, kegging, troubleshooting

If you have an at home draft system, how do you check for leaks in the CO2 side of the set up?  How often do you need to check for leaks?

Comment: Did you just get a draft system set up? Seeing a trend in questions here :)

Comment: I've been a kegger for a LONG time.  Just adding content when I think of it.

Comment: That's what I figured. Then I saw another question that mentioned leaks, and made the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drip soapy water on connections and areas of the system that are likely to leak and look for suds (that indicates a leak).  This is how you test natural gas lines for leaks, so I imagine it would work with CO2.

Comment: Or use a spray bottle.

Comment: "No bubbles, no troubles"

Answer (score 0):

When I had my kegging setup set up I don't know that I ever checked for leaks. But, it appeared to be working just fine.

My guess would be to drop any connection point into water while the system is operating, if that is a possibility, and look for bubbles. Otherwise, take soapy water and rub it all over connection points and look for bubbles. Just like a [sleeping pad](http://www.trailspace.com/articles/how-to-fix-leaky-sleeping-pad.html)!

Comment: Like the link to trailspace!